# CryptographicException: a signature method is required in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, cryptographicexception

In Visual Studio 2012, when running in Debug mode using the built-in server ("Use Visual Studio Development Server") the following code runs fine:

```
    Dim mySignedXml As SignedXml = SignResponse(doc, cert)
    Dim xml As XmlElement = mySignedXml.GetXml()
```

But when I choose "Use  Local IIS Web Server" setting in Visual Studio, the **GetXml()** method fails with this error:

```
     System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 
     A signature method is required.
```

This is on a Windows 7 x64 PC, not a server.  What change must be made to the Local IIS Web Server configuration so this code works there too?

Comment: Where is the certificate loaded from?

Comment: You asked the right question, Wiktor :-)  The IIS built-in user doesn't have access to the folder where the key file is stored, so I'll have to relocate the file. `myX509Certficate2.Import(CertificatePath, "passwordhere", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)`